# Programming a complete autonomous dji drone? take off - follow a flight path - land

Tags: dji-sdk

I want to programmed a drone to be completely autonomous. Being alone, the drone should take off at one programmed time, follow some way points and land in one programmed place. Does the dji-sdk allow that? I am thinking to buy a m100 or m200 dji drone.

Comment: "programmated" = programmed

Answer (score 2):

Yes, aircraft take-off and landing can be automated through APIs located in the DJI Mobile or Onboard SDK.

For more information please see this link for the Mobile SDK: https://developer.dji.com/mobile-sdk/documentation/introduction/component-guide-flightController.html.​​

Or this link for the Onboard SDK: https://developer.dji.com/onboard-sdk/documentation/guides/component-guide-flight-control.html​​

For Mobile Mission specific information follow this link:  https://developer.dji.com/mobile-sdk/documentation/introduction/component-guide-missions.html

And for Onboard Mission information follow this link: https://developer.dji.com/onboard-sdk/documentation/sample-doc/missions.html

Comment: I've checked the links and I see that I could automate the process for taking off and landing, but I am not sure if I could program a flight at a specified time, let the drone alone and it will start flying at that time. Is it possible?

Comment: @rafaoc You could potentially do that by using a cron job if you use the onboard sdk or by using a timer on the mobile side to control the time when you take off. But that would mean you would need the whole drone setup powered on and ready to go; so depending on the length of time it might/might not be possible (batteries will run out). Currently there is no way to program the drone to turn on at a scheduled time.