# Sleep mode or low power mode equivalent via DJI SDK?

Tags: dji-sdk

I've combed through the SDK and haven't found anything promising. I'd like to keep a Mavic Air on a "standby" mode, if at all possible. I see that I can power off the motors, but I'm not sure how significantly that will drop the current consumption. Has anyone tried to sleep a DJI programatically with the SDK?

Comment: power off motor should just do the trick. It should drop the overall power consumption by 90+ %.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the drones from DJI do not have a "standby" mode.

I'm working with a Mavic Pro and after some tedious research on the internet I've come to the conclusion that the only way to keep a DJI drone powered an arbitrary amount of time is to use an autonomous charging platform.

From my experience with Mavic Pro, the battery of the drone lasts ~1.5-2h when not flying and the motors are kept off. The remote Controller discharged faster while being kept on (~1.5h).
The Mavic Pro Remote Controller has two USB outputs, which enables connecting to the smartphone and charging simultaneously.

A related question can be found here:
[Programming a complete autonomous dji drone? take off - follow a flight path - land](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50472362/programming-a-complete-autonomous-dji-drone-take-off-follow-a-flight-path-l)